# Замена хэштегов на ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь реализовать хэштеги. Заменить каждый хэштег на ссылку.

Есть строка

**$PhotoDescrition** со значением:

```
Здесь должно быть красивое описание фотографии с использованием
#хэштегов несолько #раз. #Реализация34 #Будь_Вкурсе
```

Регулярное выражение которое я использую.

```
preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+\w*)/', '\1<a href="/search/query=\2">#\2</a>', $PhotoDescrition);
```

Но русские буквы не выводятся. Может есть более точное регулярное выражение?

Мне необходимо что-бы, хештеги имели тип: **Буквы**, **Цифры**, и **нижнее подчеркивание** *(не должно повторяться более 1 раза подряд)*

Comment: Нужен модификатор `u`

Comment: Ничего не подошло из имеющихся ответов? Нужна помощь?

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/QuzA3s

```
echo preg_replace(
  '/(^|\s)#([a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+)/u',
  '\1<a href="/search/query=\2">#\2</a>',
  'just a #text #ёжик побежал'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Необходимо что-бы, хештеги имели тип: Буквы, Цифры, и нижнее подчеркивание (не должно повторяться более 1 раза подряд)*

```
echo preg_replace(
    '~(?:^|\s)\K#([\pL\d]*_?[\pL\d]+)(?=\s|$)~u',
    '<a href="/search/query=$1">#$1</a>',
    'just a #ё_жик #te-xt #ё__жик #_text побежал'
);
```